# Program doesn't work on different devices

Tags: mysql, vb.net, backgroundworker

I have built a program that checks if the app is enabled or not. If enabled, It will execute a `BackgroundWorker` and if not, it will notify the user and will close immediately. It worked for my computer but to others, it doesn't complete the code without errors.

Here is my code:

```vb
Dim Status As String = ""
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If Status = "Enabled" Or Status = "Disabled" Then
    Else
        Status = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(Account & "Flag").InnerText.ToString
        If Status = "Enabled" Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        ElseIf Status = "Disabled" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Disabled", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Close()
        Else
            Status = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

For me, I think it doesn't start the `BackgroundWorker`from doing its job. I've tested the code by putting `MsgBox("Code 1 Success")` after the first line of code and `MsgBox("Code 2 Success")` after the second line of code and so on. And it reaches the `BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` code but it does'nt execute the code under BackgroundWorker.

Here is the BackgroundWorker1 code:

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Label1.Text = "Status: Checking"
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
    Try
        Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=85.10.205.173;port=3306;username='" & User & "';password='" & Pass & "'")
        Dim mysqlcommand As MySqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim mysqldatareader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
        mysqlconnection.Open()
        Using table As DataTable = New DataTable
            Using command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from login.accounts where Username = 'Jake';", mysqlconnection)
                Using adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
                    adapter.Fill(table)
                End Using
            End Using

            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                If row("Flag") = "enable" Then
                    Label1.Text = "Status: Enabled"
                    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Button1.Enabled = False
                    Button2.Enabled = True
                    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
                Else
                    Label1.Text = "Status: Disabled"
                    Label1.ForeColor = Color.OrangeRed
                    Button1.Enabled = True
                    Button2.Enabled = False
                    ProgressBar2.Visible = False
                End If
            Next
        End Using
        mysqlconnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Label1.Text = "No Internet Connection"
    End Try
End Sub
```

I knew that it doesn't reach this code because the `Label1.Text` didn't change, if it reaches this part of the code it must've been "Status: Checking".

What is the problem of my code? Again, It works in my computer but to others, it does not. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MSDN,

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in
>   your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface
>   through the BackgroundWorker events.

Probably the first line is causing error. It is better to invoke it on UI thread. See [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)

Side notes:

1. Your loop in `DoWork` doesn't seem right. You are looking for a flag in lines and setting enable and disable states, what if multiple lines have flag set or not set? If query is going to return only 1 line every time then you don't need the loop here
2. You should have some logging in `DoWork` event handler, so that you know what is actually happening inside.
3. Normally we don't handle the exception in `DoWork` event handler, rather use `RunWorkerCompleted` event which tells you whether any exception was occurred in the process or not. Regardless, it is a good idea to use this event in order to know that process was completed.

Comment: So what should the code be? I don't know how to do it. The code runs perfectly for my computer but when opened to a different one it doesn't execute the backgroundworker. Im confused

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes. But i can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it to work

Here is the code i've used:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10)
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=85.10.205.173;port=3306;username='" & User & "';password='" & Pass & "'")
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(20)
    Dim mysqlcommand As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(30)
    Dim mysqldatareader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(40)
    mysqlconnection.Open()
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50)
    Using table As DataTable = New DataTable
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60)
        Using command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from my.accounts where Username = 'Ray';", mysqlconnection)
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(70)
            Using adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(80)
                adapter.Fill(table)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(90)
            End Using
        End Using

        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            If row("Flag") = "enable" Then
                e.Result = "1"
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
            Else
                e.Result = "0"
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)
            End If
        Next
    End Using
    mysqlconnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    If e.ProgressPercentage = 10 Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: Checking"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    ProgressBar1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    If e.Result = "1" Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: Enabled"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True
    ElseIf e.Result = "0" Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: Disabled"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.OrangeRed
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Unknown output: " & e.Result & " . Closing", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks @sallushan